# How to get all docvecs of a model

Tags: python, k-means, gensim, doc2vec

I have around a 1000 documents, and I have trained them using gensim's doc2vec class. I need all the 1000 docvecs from the model to perform a kmeans clstering. But the maximum docvecs I'm able to get is 10. Any idea, how to get all of them?. Below is my code snippet.

`

```
tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(_d.lower()),tags=str(i)) for i, _d in enumerate(data)]

max_epochs = 100
vec_size = 20
alpha = 0.025

model = Doc2Vec(size=vec_size,
                alpha=alpha, 
                min_alpha=0.025,
                min_count=1,
                dm =1)

model.build_vocab(tagged_data)

for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    model.train(tagged_data,
                total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                epochs=model.iter)
    # decrease the learning rate
    model.alpha -= 0.0002
    # fix the learning rate, no decay
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha

X= model.docvecs.doctag_syn0 

print(X)

true_k = 3
km = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
km.fit(X)

clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
```

`

Answer (score -1):

The `tags` property of a `TaggedDocument` should be a *list* of tags.

By providing just `tags=str(i)`, you're providing a single string, which is seen as a list-of-characters. And all your lists-of-characters just have the digits '0' to '9'. Thus the model is only seeing 10 tags during training, and you only have 10 doc-vectors at the end, for tags `'0'` to `'9'`.

Use `tags=[str(i)]` instead, to supply a list with one tag. (Or even use `tags=[i]` – `Doc2Vec` can use plain int tags efficiently, as long as they're contiguous starting at `0`.)